# SQL Server - Searching string with international characters using LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pattern-matching

I have a field 'Description' which can have product descriptions with any unicode characters.
If I search for a description which contains an international character, with a LIKE condition (word searched with does not have the international character) I get the following results:

Ex: `GEWÜRZTRAMINER` is one of the descriptions.
When I do:

```
Select * from table where Description LIKE '%GEWURZTRAMINER%', it retrieves the entry.
```

When I do:

```
Select * from table where Description LIKE '%GEWURZ%', the entry is not retrieved.
```

(Note: the search condition does not include the Ü but has a U)

Is there a way around this so that I can retrieve with '%GEWURZ%' as well?

Comment: Which variant of SQL are you using?

Comment: Where do you get capital ü from? It isn't on my Swiss-German keyboard

Comment: I had just copied it from my db

Comment: With Windows' German keymapping, I press `shift-[` key to get `Ü`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For bog standard varchar, you'd have to coerce to a accent insensitive collation

```
Select 1 where 'GEWÜRZTRAMINER' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AI LIKE '%GEWURZTRAMINER%'
```

There should be no difference between the calls though for the SQL you provided.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the collation order for the column.  It should work if you use e.g. SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI